# date is storing wrong in mariadb while inserting from java

Tags: java, angular, date, mariadb

I have selected date as 8th feb 2019 in angular datepicker and in java side logs it is printed as `Fri Feb 08 00:00:00 SGT 2019` but in database it stored as `07/02/2019 16:00:00` I am using datetime format in db side. and `java.util.date` in java.
this is happening very randomly if i try gain with the same date in database it stored as `08/02/2019 00:00:00.`

database timezone is SGT.

why is it happening ?

[edited] I have selected date as 8th feb 2019 not 2nd feb ..
sorry

Comment: What is the exact type of column in the database?

Comment: I am using DateTime type

Comment: Check timezones.

Answer (score 0):

The `SGT` in  `Fri Feb 08 00:00:00 SGT 2019` denotes the timezone, whereas in the DB you have UTC time. Both times are the exactly same moment in history.

Selecting dates in browser always happens in user's timezone. You need to adjust for that if you want the time using UTC.

Answer (score 0):

The property `serverTimezone` with the value `SGT` should be added to the JDBC connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://<address>:<port>/<database>?serverTimezone=SGT
```

From MySQL documentation: [6.3.11 Datetime types processing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-datetime-types-processing.html)